# Accidentally deleted nodes in compositing tab. Can't recover it?

Tags: rendering, node-editor, render-layers, compositing-nodes

I accidentally deleted the 'Render Layer' and 'Composite' Node. I panicked and didn't know what to do, so I thought maybe if I close my file, itll come back when i open it again. So I closed my file, and obviously saved it because it had all my progress, but my dumb self didn't think through that it might save the action of deleted nodes as well.

I have tried everything to reverse this but nothing works. I tried manually adding these nodes. I do get the composite node fine, but the 'Render Layer' has missing bits.
I even uninstalled and re-installed Blender to fix this, but nothing.

I have attached images with the original 'Render Layer' node and the one I'm getting now (which doesn't have all the properties that I need).

[image]

[image]

**Link**: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zmwdv.jpg

**TLDR**;
Accidentally deleted 'Render Layer' and 'Composite' Nodes. Can't recover them no matter what I do. Manually added nodes have missing properties.

Comment: please use the tools from this site to make images visible as part of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not worry, this looks easy to fix, even if this diagnosis is wrong.

The image looks like render passes that were previously enabled have been turned off, and thus aren't showing up in the render layer node. Check this manual page for information on render passes. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/layers/passes.html

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't understand how to make sense of the info in the link you provided as Im still new to Blender. 

But I figured out how to bring back these properties. Just had to turn on 'Denoising' under Passes in View Layer Properties tab. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. :)

Comment: @AqsaN please write an answer detailing what you did so that other users with the same problem can learn from your experience.

Comment: Passes are kinda like raw ingredients that may have led to the ultimate product, AKA the output image, AKA the "Combined" render pass. Or sometimes they are just data that the render engine can "pick up while it's there" for you to use in compositing. Enabling other passes besides "Combined" adds extra available outputs to the Render Layers compositor node.